# Archive Page Pagination not working

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, custom-post-type-archives

I am using the following template for a custom post type. The pagination does not work as you can see at http://www.xava.ie/testimonials

Any hints as to why it is not working for me?

```
<?php
    global $paged;
    get_header();
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $products->have_posts() ) {
        while( $products->have_posts() ) {
            $products->the_post();
            ?>
                <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
                <div class='content'>
                    <?php the_content() ?>

                </div>
            <?php
        }
        wp_pagenavi();
        echo "Number of post pages = ",$products->max_num_pages;
        if($products->max_num_pages>1){?>
                <p class="pager">
            <?php
            for($i=1;$i<=$products->max_num_pages;$i++){?>
                <?php $query_string = "?paged=".$i; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $query_string; ?>" <?php echo ($paged==$i)? 'class="selected"':'';?>><?php echo $i;?></a>
            <?php }?>
            </p>
        <?php }         
    }
    else {
        echo 'Oh ohm no testimonials!';
    }       
    get_sidebar('Primary'); get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Probably because you missed `pre_get_posts`. Search our site for better solutions.

Comment: Do you have an English site?

Comment: The last link in my profile points to the English site I am contributing to. Why is that relevant? :)

Comment: You recommended that I search your site for better solutions.

Comment: No, [our site, WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-get-posts?sort=votes&pagesize=50).